# Content offscreen to animate in without negative SEO

Tags: seo, google-search-console, mobile

The design for the mobile version of my site calls for the body text to slide in from offscreen when the user clicks a "Get Started" button.

The problem is that Google considers this to be "content offscreen" in their mobile-friendly test. How can I update this so that there's no penalty for the content being offscreen?

Comment: You don't have to have a perfect score on the mobile friendly test.  There is no penalty unless there are enough things wrong that Google says that it isn't mobile friendly.

Comment: It isn't clear how much is on the page initially other than "Get started", but generally forcing users to press a button to access the content isn't user friendly, let alone mobile friendly.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, in their search results, Google does say that it's not mobile friendly. We didn't want there to be a block of text smack in the middle of the page, so we had a more minimalistic design with the content coming in afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just having the content off screen, I would start with the content hidden.   When it needs to be shown, first make the content visible (but still off screen), and then slide it into place.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, I'll try that out when I get a chance